# Add state and lifecycle methods to Function Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How can I rewrite this code in a functional component?

I want to add state and lifecycle methods to the Functional Component.

This is the code is for `componentDidMount` and `componentWillReceiveProps` from the class component.

```
class TherapistProfiles extends React.Component {

    state = {
        page: 1,
        therapists: [],
        hasMore: true,
        resultsTitle: 'Top Therapist Profiles',
        pageLoading: false
    }

    topProfilesUrl = 'therapists/top/profiles'
    searchByNameUrl = 'therapists/search/name'

    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.getTopTherapists()
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps = (newProps) => {

        let apiData = newProps.apiData;

        if (apiData.topProfiles && apiData.topProfiles.success) {
            let therapists = apiData.topProfiles.therapists
            let hasMore = true

            if (therapists.length < 10) {
                hasMore = false
            }

            this.setState(() => ({
                therapists: this.state.therapists.concat(therapists),
                hasMore: hasMore,
                pageLoading: false
            }))

        } else if (apiData.therapistsByName && apiData.therapistsByName.success) {
            let therapists = apiData.therapistsByName.therapists,
                resTitle = therapists.length ?
                    `Results for "${this.state.searchName}"`
                    : `Looks like there are no results for "${this.state.searchName}"`

            this.setState(() => ({
                therapists: therapists,
                hasMore: false,
                pageLoading: false,
                resultsTitle: resTitle
            }))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You will can make use of the useState hook for the component state, and useEffect hook to replace ComponentDidUpdate and ComponentWillReceiveProps.

First, you use the `useState` hook to maintain the component state.

```
const [ therapistProfilesState, setTherapistProfilesState ] = useState({
  page: 1,
  therapists: [],
  hasMore: true,
  resultsTitle: 'Top Therapist Profiles',
  pageLoading: false
});
```

Next, to replace `ComponentDidMount`, you set the dependency array as an empty array such that the `useEffect` hook will run once on init:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getTopTherapists()
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}, []);
```

And as for `ComponentWillReceiveProps`, you will have another `useEffect` hook with `props` as part of the dependency array, such that it will run when `props` are updated. I won't write the full code as it is too long, but here is a starting point:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (something) {
    setTherapistProfilesState(...);
  }
}, [props]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such things in function components as you are looking for `componentDidMount` or `componentWillReceiveProps` like in class based component. Instead you can use `useEffect` hook. Read from the documentation:

> If you're familiar with React class lifecycle methods, you can think of `useEffect` Hook as `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount` combined.

Let me give you an easy example:

```
const Home = () => {
   // defining states
   const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

   // implementing side effects below
   // similarly like lifecycle events in class component
   useEffect(() => {
      console.log('your component is ready to fetch data');

      // maybe you want to fetch data from an API here
   }, []);

   return <h1>Hello function component</h1>;
}
```

Suggested read: [Using the Effect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

I hope that helps!

Comment: I think the problem is that the OP wants us to do all the work for them and transform their class based component into a function component.

Comment: @zero298 I guess with my provided example I'm helping the OP with a good start to jump into `useEffect` hook usage, of course it requires further implementation and reading as always. But it gives the idea.