# infinite fetch data in useEffect in react.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hi I'm trying to fetch data using personally built axios function named `fetchMerchant`.

I give dependencies in useEffect hook with `fullData` but it seems infinite looping after render and re render.

In my opinion, It should be rendered once after useEffect hooks because of dependency `fullData` given as a array.

How can I prevent infinite rendering after useEffect ?

```js
  const BoardPage: FC =() => {
  const [fullData, setData] = useState<ContentType>({} as ContentType);
  const fetchData = async() => {
    try{
      const [,response] = await fetchMerchant();
      console.log(response);
      setData(response);
    } catch(error){
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("board rendered");

    fetchData();
  },[fullData]) 
  return(
    <>
      <Board data={fullData} /> 
    </> 
  )
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add state and lifecycle methods to Function Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60211606/add-state-and-lifecycle-methods-to-function-components)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's running infinitely because of how your hook is setup. When you place something in the brackets at the end of the hook `[fullData]` it means that the hook will fire when that value changes. You don't want that to happen in this case because `fetchData()` inside of the hook will cause `fullData` to change thus firing the hook again. If you leave the brackets empty like so it should only fire once when the component is mounted

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("board rendered");

    fetchData();
  },[])
```